# Can anyone recommend a scriptable Java profiler?

Tags: java, automation, profiler

I want to automate our field case analysis.
We sometimes get HPROF files from crashes of our product in production, and look for "typical" problems we know of. Examples:

- specific threads creating problems
- specific classes filling up the heap
- etc.

Currently the HPROF analysis is done manually.
I want to automate that.
Does anyone know of a good Java profiler who allows that? I know Yourkit and JProfiler quite well, and am unaware of such features.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find something in [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net). It integrates the OQL scripting engine and allows you to persist your own queries so you can easily run them against various heap dumps. However, it is not yet ready for headless analysis.

The OQL implementation in **VisualVM** is based on the one you can find in **jhat** and it means that it is javascript based - in addition to "standard" **OQL** queries it allows you to use plain javascript thus increasing the flexibility many times.

There are few examples of the javascript analysis bundled with VisualVM or you can use the user mailing list to get help.

Cheers!